# Rails, include own name in json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, dynamic

In C#:

```
var cities = clients.Select(c => 
                                new { 
                                      DisplayText = c.CityName, 
                                      Value = c.CityId 
                            });
return Json(new { Result = "OK", Options = cities });
```

How perform this in Rails?

Target json:

```
{
 "Result" : "OK",
 "Options": [
              { "DisplayText" : "clientName1", "Value" : 1},
              { "DisplayText" : "clientName2", "Value" : 2},
            ]
}
```

Comment: Please add an example of returned JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
cities = Clients.all.map { |client| {:DisplayText => client.CityName, :Value => client.CityID} }

render :json => {:Result => 'OK', :Options => cities}
```

Note that the capitalization is not really common in ruby.

I would have done something like that :

```
cities = Clients.all.map { |client| {:displayText => client.cityName, :value => client.cityID} }

render :json => {:result => 'OK', :options => cities}
```

Comment: Great answer! Only thing to note is the naming convention is not really ruby.

Not really the point of this question, i know, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Exactly, I will precise this in the answer

Comment: I know, but for one nice jquery plugin, that I'm using in asp.net mvc, it required.